# How to check the correctly ping response time using javascript in client-side?

Tags: javascript, ajax, response, ping, client-side

I have checked the ping response time following code. But this value differ about `100ms` to real value.
How to check the correctly ping response time using javascript in client-side?

```js
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsfiddle.net/',
        method: 'HEAD',
        start_time: new Date().getTime(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert('This request took '+(new Date().getTime() - this.start_time)+' ms');
        }
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell you can't really, how exact do you need the value to be? In my tests it only different by ~10ms

Comment: That is ok, but as you can see it's different around 100ms on my side.

Comment: Please take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/sq75n3wu/

Comment: 120 vs. 114 and 181 vs. 167 - unfortunately I cannot reproduce those issues on my end.

Comment: If so, could you let me know how I can implement above function using $http of angularjs without $ajax?

Comment: Use `performance.now()`